# Color for Widget.AppCompat.SearchView clear text icon

Tags: android, searchview

I want to set color for my SearchView clear text icon(multiplication sign):

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
     <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/grey</item>
</style>
```

And this is my SearchView :

```
             <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle"
                android:transitionGroup="true" />
```

Which property should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this in your code behind of your activity. Something as followed:

```
SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view):

int searchCloseIconButtonId = SearchView.getContext().getResources()
        .getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
ImageView searchClose = searchView.findViewById(searchCloseIconButtonId);
searchClose.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: I receive an error on 'appcompat' in ´android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn´

Comment: @Ali I've edited my answer, can you give that a shot?